# Adding constant spread to yield curve using ZeroSpreadedTermStructure

Tags: python, quantlib

Starting from a yield curve `ycHandle` (a `YieldTermStructureHandle` object), I would like to add a constant spread using the `ZeroSpreadedTermStructure` method. I did the following (working in Python with QuantLib 1.8):

```
shift = 0
spread = ql.SimpleQuote(shift)
shiftedCurve = ql.ZeroSpreadedTermStructure(ycHandle,ql.QuoteHandle(spread))

def plotCurve(ycHandle, maxTen=25, lab=''):
    # function taking a yield curve handle and plotting it
    call = ql.TARGET()
    tv = [] # tenor vector
    rv = [] # rate vector
    for _ in range(12*1,12*maxTen):
        dt = call.advance(ql.Date.todaysDate(), 2, ql.Days) + 30*_
        tv.append(dc.yearFraction(today,dt))
        rv.append(ycHandle.zeroRate(dt,dc,ql.Compounded,ql.Annual).rate())
    plt.plot(tv,rv, label=lab)

plt.figure()
plotCurve(ycHandle)
plotCurve(shiftedCurve)
```

Unfortunately the **two curves do not overlap** although I have shifted `ycHandle` by 0. I suspect this might be linked to the compounding, have tried to change all to `ql.Annual` or `ql.Continuous` but unfortunately was unsuccessful.

Comment: You're passing `zcHandle` to build the shifted curve but plotting `ycHandle`. Just a typo when copying the code, or is there something else going on?

Comment: Just a typo, thanks for pointing it out, I edited the code. Could you reproduce the issue?

Comment: No, I couldn't. May you post a self-contained snippet? The one above relies on a few missing variables (`dc`, for instance, but it's not the only one).

Comment: By writing a self-contained code snippet the problem went away. The issue seemed to come from the YieldCurve objects that were produced by a NelsonSiegel fitting procedure. Thanks!